# How to use curl post and recive json data in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

This is a website and I am trying to get a download link using curl.
First i try some thing like this

```
$data2 = 'fs_csrf='. $fs_csrf[1] . '&DownloadForm%5Bpwd%5D=&ajax=download-form&undefined=undefined';
$curl->post('https://www.fshare.vn/login',$data2);
$curl->get('https://www.fshare.vn/login');
```

But evething does not work. When fshare.vn/login was reloaded. It does not give me download link.
Then i try:

```
$data2 = 'fs_csrf='. $fs_csrf[1] . '&DownloadForm%5Bpwd%5D=&ajax=download-form&undefined=undefined';
                    $data_string = json_encode($data2); 
                    echo "{$data2}";
                    $url ='https://www.fshare.vn/download/get';
                    $ch = curl_init('https://www.fshare.vn/download/get');
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
                        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
                        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
                    );                                                                                                                   

                    $jsresult = curl_exec($ch);
                    echo "{$jsresult}";
```

But it still does not work

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: does the curl statement work correctly when performed manually in your command line interpreter? (terminal, git bash emulator, etc?)

Comment: Please debug your code and check error_log.

Comment: What's in $fs_csrf[1] ?  Isn't $fs_csrf a simple string?

Comment: If you're using Windows, you may need to install the Certificate Authority bundle file to make cURL requests to https sites. You can get the file (`ca-bundle.crt`) from [this repository](https://github.com/bagder/ca-bundle/raw/master/ca-bundle.crt), place it somewhere in your system, and note it's file path. Then, in `php.ini`, set `curl.cainfo` to the absolute file path of said bundle file.

Comment: My full code here mediafire .com/view/8p85lqao3acdta2/fshare.txt
I am trying to login to a website and get download link. Code login website is ok but this site use some special trick to give back download link and I cannot pass it.

Comment: $fs_csrf is a special string server give back every time web browser reload.  It is necessary to login and get download link